# Editando dia com AngularJS?

Tags: html5, angularjs

Tenho uma tela onde cadastro dias, horários, entre outros e uma tela para fazer a edição desses dados, caso necessário. Quando clico no botão para editar tal data eu recebo os dados direitinho.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é que na tela de edição eu quero que o campo data seja `type=date`, para aparecer o calendário e a pessoa escolher a nova data, porém, dessa forma a data **20/09/2019** não aparece no campos, só aparece que o campo for do tipo `text` (`type=text`).

Alguém sabe como ajustar isso?

Segue o `html` com o *campo de data*

```
<form name="formGrade">
    <div>
       Data
    </div>
    <div>
       <input class="form-control" type="date" 
              ng-model="agenda.data" 
              name="dia" id="" required />
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var getHorario = function(){
    var id = $scope.id;
    var idempresa = $scope.idempresa;
    var opcao = 'pegar horario';

    $http.get(getUrlOptionPrefix + opcao + '&id=' + id+ '&idempresa=' + idempresa)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.agenda = response.data;
    })
}
getHorario();
```

Comment: cade seu código?

Comment: O html está aí na descrição! Não entendi.

Comment: código minimo e verificável, ou seja, todo o código do problema... cade o javascript?

Comment: Acabei de postar...

Comment: Esse problema é porque a data está vindo no formato errado (`A questão é que na tela de edição eu quero que o campo data seja "type=date", para aparecer o calendário e a pessoa escolher a nova data, PORÉM, dessa forma a data "20/09/2019" não aparece no campos... Só aparece que o campo for do tipo text "type=text". Alguém sabe como ajustar isso?`) teria que ser **2019-06-20** para dar certo, exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/swh63fyk/

Comment: Agora consegui.... Segui o exemplo do link acima. Valeu @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve converter a data para o formato ISO: yyyy-mm-dd

```
agenda.data = agenda.data.split('/').reverse().join('-');
```